# React not supporting map method

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

Following react.js tutorial I've got an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

I have a state like this :

```
this.state = {
      input: '',
      array1:[{name:"john"}, {name:"Tom"}, {name:"Walt"}, {name:"Peter"}]
}
```

and shared this as props to ResponseList component

```
<ResponseList apiRes = {this.state.array1} />
```

In the ResponseList I can't map through the array1

```
const ResponseList = ({ array1 }) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {
        array1.map((data,x) => data.name)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: you passed apiRes into your component; therefore, you must instead use apiRes in your response list component

Comment: Thanks  @Robert Terrell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `apiRes` as a props param, not `array1`. Make the name same.

```
const ResponseList = ({ apiRes }) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {
        apiRes.map((data,x) => data.name)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply can change the component to:

```
<ResponseList array1={this.state.array1} />
```